# How to use Routify with Snowpack and Svelte

Tags: svelte, snowpack, routify

I need to install Routify to Svelte app which is running with Snowpack.

Current documentation is very narrow and only shows an installation with Rollap.

I've tried a template to achieve it but I get errors on the Routify side.

How can I achieve this?

Any help is very much appreciated. Also open to any other Path-based SPA router recommendations that work well with Snowpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Started a project with [an official Snowpack template](https://github.com/snowpackjs/snowpack/tree/main/create-snowpack-app/app-template-svelte-typescript) using `npx create-snowpack-app [DIR NAME] --template @snowpack/app-template-svelte-typescript` (Replace `[DIR NAME]` with folder name).

And then did everything below:

Install npm-run-all:

```
npm i npm-run-all
```

/package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "run-p routify snp",
    "build": "routify -b && routify export && snowpack build",
    "test": "web-test-runner \"src/**/*.test.js\"",
    "routify": "routify",
    "snp": "snowpack dev",
},
...
"routify": {
    "extensions": "svelte,html,svx,md",
    "dynamicImports": false,
    "routifyDir": "src/.routify"
}
```

/snowpack.config.js:

```
  packageOptions: {
    knownEntrypoints: ["@roxi/routify/runtime/buildRoutes"]
  },
```